# What is causing the memory spike in my Django file upload code?

Tags: python, django, apache, file-upload, amazon-s3

My system memory usage jumps from 30mb up to 300mb+ when I upload a 4.8mb file.

Basically a user uploads a (for example) 4.8mb jpeg and it is uploaded to webfaction, then stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.

I think one thing that is killing me is that I'm using easy_thumbnails to generate 3 files which are also stored in the S3 bucket.

**update 2:** At this point I think my main problem is that the memory spikes but is never released. I'm going to start looking into running gc.collect() after the Photo.objects.create() is done. It also looks like sorl-thumbnail may be a better choice and sounds like it's better at working with remote storages.

**update 1:** I'm using django-debug-toolbar and have it intercepting redirects. I'm now getting some useful data. It tells me I've performed 20 db queries (eek) but worse than that (I believe) is that boto (what i'm using for my file storage) is logging 124 messages. It looks like it's sending each one of the files separately. Maybe that is normal, maybe not? Either way it seems pretty high.

Once the file is uploaded the memory never goes back down unless I reset apache.

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from easy_thumbnails.fields import ThumbnailerImageField
from django.conf import settings
import datetime
import os
import string
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

...

class Photo(models.Model):
    """
    A photo belongs to a user. A photo has a preview size and the original which
    is referenced when printing or generating the PDF for print.

    """
    def original_resolution(instance, filename):
        """
        Returns a path to upload the image to. The path is created with the
        website's slug and the current year. Using Amazon S3 for CDN storage

        """
        today = datetime.datetime.now()

        return 'uploads/{0}/{1}/{2}/{8}-{3}-{4}-{5}-{6}-{7}'.format(
            instance.owner.pk,
            today.year,
            today.month,
            today.day,
            today.hour,
            today.minute,
            today.second,
            clean_filename(filename),
            'original')

    def thumbnail_resolution(instance, filename):
        """
        Returns a path to upload the image to. The path is created with the
        website's slug and the current year. Using Amazon S3 for CDN storage

        """
        today = datetime.datetime.now()

        return 'uploads/{0}/{1}/{2}/{8}-{3}-{4}-{5}-{6}-{7}'.format(
            instance.owner.pk,
            today.year,
            today.month,
            today.day,
            today.hour,
            today.minute,
            today.second,
            clean_filename(filename),
            'thumbnail')

    def editor_resolution(instance, filename):
        """
        Returns a path to upload the image to. The path is created with the
        website's slug and the current year. Using Amazon S3 for CDN storage

        """
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        return 'uploads/{0}/{1}/{2}/{8}-{3}-{4}-{5}-{6}-{7}'.format(
            instance.owner.pk,
            today.year,
            today.month,
            today.day,
            today.hour,
            today.minute,
            today.second,
            clean_filename(filename),
            'editor')

    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)

    width = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    original = ThumbnailerImageField(
        upload_to=original_resolution,
        resize_source=dict(size=(0, 3100), crop="scale", quality=99),
        height_field='height',
        width_field='width',
        verbose_name=u'Choose Photo')

    thumbnail = ThumbnailerImageField(
        upload_to=thumbnail_resolution,
        resize_source=dict(size=(0, 100), crop="scale"),
        blank=True,
        null=True)

    editor = ThumbnailerImageField(
        upload_to=editor_resolution,
        resize_source=dict(size=(0, 1000), crop="scale"),
        blank=True,
        null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('photos:proxy_editor_image', kwargs={
            'pk': self.pk})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Photo #{}".format(self.pk)

...
```

And here is my view that handles the upload:

```
@login_required
def upload_photo(request):
    """
    Creates and saves a new photo.
    """

    if request.is_ajax():
        response = {}

        form = UploadPhotoForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_photo = Photo.objects.create(
                original=form.cleaned_data['original'],
                thumbnail=form.cleaned_data['original'],
                editor=form.cleaned_data['original'],
                owner=form.cleaned_data['owner']
            )
            response['result'] = 'success'
            response['message'] = 'Photo successfully uploaded!'
            response['new_photo_pk'] = new_photo.pk
            response['thumbnail_path'] = new_photo.thumbnail.url
            response['editor_path'] = new_photo.editor.url
            response['original_path'] = new_photo.original.url
            response['editor_path_proxy'] = new_photo.get_absolute_url()

        else:
            response['result'] = 'fail'
            response['message'] = 'The photo failed to upload.'
            response['new_photo_pk'] = False

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response),
            content_type='application/json'
        )

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadPhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            Photo.objects.create(
                original=form.cleaned_data['original'],
                thumbnail=form.cleaned_data['original'],
                editor=form.cleaned_data['original'],
                owner=form.cleaned_data['owner']
            )
            messages.success(request, "Photo successfully uploaded!")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "The photo failed to upload.")

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('photos:list'))
```

I'm stumped and I'm probably just not understanding something. Help?

I've been struggling with this memory usage issue for a few months now and have finally narrowed it down to this.

FWIW, I'm on django1.6 python 2.7, webfaction hosting, amazon s3 buckets for storage.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the exact same issue with django's FileField and s3 bucket storage

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to your Apache setup (worker vs. prefork). The process, whatever it is, chews up a bunch of memory and then never releases it. We had the same thing going on and ended up taking pieces of the app and putting them in separate wsgi process groups which we would stop the memory heavy requests from causing all the wsgi processes to consume a massive amount of memory.

I ended up having an in depth conversation with the creator of mod_wsgi as a result of this question: [Django, python, mod_wsgi and Apache worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604995/django-python-mod-wsgi-and-apache-worker)

I used htop to diagnose some of the memory heavy processes. Then, based on my findings, setup multiple WSGIDaemonProcess directives in apache, like so...

```
WSGIDaemonProcess article-app processes=10 threads=5 display-name=articles user=myuser group=mygroup python-path=/home/admin/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIDaemonProcess account-app-memory-heavy processes=2 threads=5 display-name=account user=myuser group=mygroup python-path=/home/admin/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

You can also use these options to debug and possibly improve performance:

```
inactivity-timeout=300 maximum-requests=100
```

Then in my VirtualHost directive...

```
<Location /article/>
    WSGIProcessGroup articles
</Location>
<Location /account/>
    WSGIProcessGroup account
</Location>
```

Now you can limit your memory heavy upload to 1 or 2 processes and have N other processes to serve the rest of your app and not consume too much memory. In our case our article app consumes 143M per wsgi process and our account app consumes 337M. We limit the account app to 2 processes and the article to 10 which creates a very predictable memory footprint.

Comment: Ah, I've read about this, some people had even moved their Django admin into that separate group but I think that was so the main group didn't have to concern itself with holding admin URLs in memory. ....or something like that. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly because WebFaction as far as I know still uses an out of date mod_wsgi and possibly even Apache 2.2. There is an issue with large file uploads if they are trickled in very slowly in small chunks. Use the latest mod_wsgi version and preferably Apache 2.4, which has other fixes in it related to memory usage and you may see better results.

Comment: I think you're correct with WF's mod_wsgi, however, I was testing this locally (OSX 10.10.2 w' runserver) to see if I could get it to act up and it did. One process would be sitting at ~30mb and as soon as I started uploading (using the view) it would jump up to  ~300mb. Then it would come back down to ~80mb. Never back down to 30mb. If I did another upload it would spike up then return back to ~80 or ~90. I've also been reading up on easy_thumbnails and it seems to be a pretty common problem. Argh... That being said, I'm going to make sure that mod_wsgi and Apache are up to date on both envs.

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading mod_wsgi on WebFaction isn't a simple process. You can't just compile latest mod_wsgi from source code as their Apache installation is missing the bits required to do that. You therefore have to also build Apache yourself. Much mucking around.